# I can't make the plane move, where did I code wrong?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

```
// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    // get the user's vertical input
    verticalInput = Input.GetAxis(Vertical);

    // move the plane forward at a constant rate
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.deltaTime);


    // tilt the plane up/down based on up/down arrow keys
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * rotationSpeed * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime);
}
```

i don't know where i went wrong in this code that my plane doesn't fly. Can anyone show me how to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are using FixedDeltaTime instead of deltaTime because you are using the fixed update method.

make sure speed and rotation speed don't equal zero .

We pass in a string into GetAxis . This script should work Fine

```
void Start()
{

}

// Update is called once per frame
void FixedUpdate()
{
    // get the user's vertical input
    verticalInput = Input.GetAxis("Vertical");

    // move the plane forward at a constant rate
    transform.Translate(Vector3.forward * speed * Time.fixedDeltaTime);


    // tilt the plane up/down based on up/down arrow keys
    transform.Rotate(Vector3.right * rotationSpeed * verticalInput * Time.deltaTime);
}
```